# Problem updating linux image 3.2.0-26 generic to 3.2.0-26.41

Tags: updates

Here are the details of failed package operation.

```
installArchives() failed: 
Extracting templates from packages: 50%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%

Extracting templates from packages: 50%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%

Extracting templates from packages: 50%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%

Extracting templates from packages: 50%%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 280864 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace cron 3.0pl1-120ubuntu3 (using .../cron_3.0pl1-120ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
cron stop/waiting
Unpacking replacement cron ...
Preparing to replace libgnutls26:i386 2.12.14-5ubuntu3 (using .../libgnutls26_2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1_i386.deb) ...
De-configuring libgnutls26 ...
Unpacking replacement libgnutls26:i386 ...
Preparing to replace libgnutls26 2.12.14-5ubuntu3 (using .../libgnutls26_2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgnutls26 ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libgnutls26:i386 (2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libgnutls26 (2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 280864 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 0.6.1-0ubuntu3 (using .../gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4_0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 ...
Preparing to replace libdbusmenu-gtk4 0.6.1-0ubuntu3 (using .../libdbusmenu-gtk4_0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdbusmenu-gtk4 ...
Preparing to replace gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 0.6.1-0ubuntu3 (using .../gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4_0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 ...
Preparing to replace libdbusmenu-glib4 0.6.1-0ubuntu3 (using .../libdbusmenu-glib4_0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdbusmenu-glib4 ...
Preparing to replace libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 0.6.1-0ubuntu3 (using .../libdbusmenu-gtk3-4_0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 ...
Preparing to replace libmtp-common 1.1.3-1 (using .../libmtp-common_1.1.3-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmtp-common ...
Preparing to replace libmtp-runtime 1.1.3-1 (using .../libmtp-runtime_1.1.3-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmtp-runtime ...
Preparing to replace libmtp9 1.1.3-1 (using .../libmtp9_1.1.3-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmtp9 ...
Preparing to replace libxkbfile1 1:1.0.7-1 (using .../libxkbfile1_1%%3a1.0.7-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libxkbfile1 ...
Preparing to replace desktop-file-utils 0.20-0ubuntu2 (using .../desktop-file-utils_0.20-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement desktop-file-utils ...
Preparing to replace nautilus-sendto-empathy 3.4.2-0ubuntu1 (using .../nautilus-sendto-empathy_3.4.2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement nautilus-sendto-empathy ...
Preparing to replace empathy 3.4.2-0ubuntu1 (using .../empathy_3.4.2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement empathy ...
Preparing to replace empathy-common 3.4.2-0ubuntu1 (using .../empathy-common_3.4.2.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement empathy-common ...
Preparing to replace kate-data 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../kate-data_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement kate-data ...
Preparing to replace libkdeclarative5 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkdeclarative5_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkdeclarative5 ...
Preparing to replace libnepomuksync4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libnepomuksync4_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libnepomuksync4 ...
Preparing to replace kde-runtime 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../kde-runtime_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement kde-runtime ...
Preparing to replace kdoctools 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../kdoctools_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement kdoctools ...
Preparing to replace kdelibs-bin 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../kdelibs-bin_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement kdelibs-bin ...
Preparing to replace libkjsembed4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkjsembed4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkjsembed4 ...
Preparing to replace libkemoticons4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkemoticons4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkemoticons4 ...
Preparing to replace libkdesu5 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkdesu5_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkdesu5 ...
Preparing to replace libplasma3 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libplasma3_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libplasma3 ...
Preparing to replace libkrosscore4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkrosscore4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkrosscore4 ...
Preparing to replace libkcmutils4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkcmutils4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkcmutils4 ...
Preparing to replace libkde3support4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkde3support4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkde3support4 ...
Preparing to replace libkmediaplayer4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkmediaplayer4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkmediaplayer4 ...
Preparing to replace libkdewebkit5 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkdewebkit5_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkdewebkit5 ...
Preparing to replace libkparts4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkparts4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkparts4 ...
Preparing to replace libknewstuff3-4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libknewstuff3-4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libknewstuff3-4 ...
Preparing to replace libknotifyconfig4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libknotifyconfig4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libknotifyconfig4 ...
Preparing to replace libnepomukutils4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libnepomukutils4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libnepomukutils4 ...
Preparing to replace libnepomukquery4a 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libnepomukquery4a_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libnepomukquery4a ...
Preparing to replace libkpty4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkpty4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkpty4 ...
Preparing to replace libkfile4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkfile4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkfile4 ...
Preparing to replace libkio5 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkio5_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkio5 ...
Preparing to replace libnepomuk4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libnepomuk4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libnepomuk4 ...
Preparing to replace libkntlm4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkntlm4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkntlm4 ...
Preparing to replace libkjsapi4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkjsapi4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkjsapi4 ...
Preparing to replace libkdnssd4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkdnssd4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkdnssd4 ...
Preparing to replace libkidletime4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkidletime4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkidletime4 ...
Preparing to replace libkdeui5 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkdeui5_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkdeui5 ...
Preparing to replace libkdecore5 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkdecore5_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkdecore5 ...
Preparing to replace kde-runtime-data 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../kde-runtime-data_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement kde-runtime-data ...
Preparing to replace katepart 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../katepart_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement katepart ...
Preparing to replace kdelibs5-data 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../kdelibs5-data_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement kdelibs5-data ...
Preparing to replace kdelibs5-plugins 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../kdelibs5-plugins_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement kdelibs5-plugins ...
Preparing to replace libkhtml5 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkhtml5_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkhtml5 ...
Preparing to replace libktexteditor4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libktexteditor4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libktexteditor4 ...
Preparing to replace libsolid4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libsolid4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libsolid4 ...
Preparing to replace libnepomukdatamanagement4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libnepomukdatamanagement4_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libnepomukdatamanagement4 ...
Preparing to replace plasma-scriptengine-javascript 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../plasma-scriptengine-javascript_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement plasma-scriptengine-javascript ...
Preparing to replace libthreadweaver4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libthreadweaver4_4%%3a4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libthreadweaver4 ...
Preparing to replace libkatepartinterfaces4 4:4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1 (using .../libkatepartinterfaces4_4%%3a4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libkatepartinterfaces4 ...
Preparing to replace xserver-common 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.2 (using .../xserver-common_2%%3a1.11.4-0ubuntu10.3_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement xserver-common ...
Preparing to replace xserver-xorg-core 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.2 (using .../xserver-xorg-core_2%%3a1.11.4-0ubuntu10.3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement xserver-xorg-core ...
Processing triggers for hal ...
Regenerating hal fdi cache ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic (3.2.0-26.41) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 33: /etc/default/grub: tmpfs: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.26.28); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up cron (3.0pl1-120ubuntu4) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/default/cron ...
cron start/running, process 1768
Setting up libdbusmenu-glib4 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libdbusmenu-gtk4 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libmtp-common (1.1.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libmtp9 (1.1.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libmtp-runtime (1.1.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libxkbfile1 (1:1.0.7-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up desktop-file-utils (0.20-0ubuntu3) ...

Configuration file `/etc/gnome/defaults.list'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** defaults.list (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
Installing new version of config file /etc/gnome/defaults.list ...
Setting up empathy-common (3.4.2.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nautilus-sendto-empathy (3.4.2.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up empathy (3.4.2.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up kate-data (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkdecore5 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkdeui5 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkdeclarative5 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libnepomuk4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libnepomuksync4 (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkcmutils4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkpty4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkdesu5 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libsolid4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkio5 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libnepomukquery4a (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libnepomukutils4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkparts4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkdewebkit5 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkdnssd4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkemoticons4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkfile4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkjsapi4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libktexteditor4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkhtml5 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkidletime4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkmediaplayer4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libknewstuff3-4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libknotifyconfig4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libnepomukdatamanagement4 (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libthreadweaver4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libplasma3 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up kde-runtime-data (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkde3support4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkjsembed4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkntlm4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkrosscore4 (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up kdelibs5-data (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up kdoctools (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up kdelibs-bin (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libkatepartinterfaces4 (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up katepart (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up kdelibs5-plugins (4:4.8.4a-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up plasma-scriptengine-javascript (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up kde-runtime (4:4.8.4-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up xserver-common (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.3) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
Error in function: 
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic (3.2.0-26.41) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 33: /etc/default/grub: tmpfs: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.26.28); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have any space left under /boot partition, i.e.:

```
df -h /boot
```

Typically this is a problem if there is no space left on boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

Running this has a good chance of cleaning up your problems:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```