# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers when trying to update linux kernel

Tags: kernel, updates, dpkg

I downloaded all the necessary files to update the linux kernel version which is currently `5.13.0-39-generic` to version `5.16.12-051612-generic` :

`linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_amd64.deb`
`linux-headers-5.16.12-051612_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_all.deb`
`linux-image-unsigned-5.16.12-051612-generic_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_amd64.deb`
`linux-modules-5.16.12-051612-generic_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_amd64.deb`

 After this I installed them all using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and the I get a few problems I wasn't able to solve:

```
(Reading database ... 461219 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) over (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.16.12-051612_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.16.12-051612 (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) over (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-5.16.12-051612-generic_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.16.12-051612-generic (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) over (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.16.12-051612-generic_5.16.12-051612.202203021142_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.16.12-051612-generic (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) over (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic:
 linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.9.
 linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic depends on libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1); however:
  Package libssl3 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-5.16.12-051612 (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.16.12-051612-generic (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.16.12-051612-generic (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.16.12-051612-generic (5.16.12-051612.202203021142) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.16.12-051612-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.18.0-051800-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.18.0-051800-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.12-051612-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.16.12-051612-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic
```

I tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/900611/1598344
and this: https://askubuntu.com/a/159769/1598344
but it didn't work.

space left under /boot partition:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       219G  161G   48G  78% /
```

Comment: Is it Ubuntu? Which release? Why would you install mainline kernels? These deb packages are incompatible with the current Ubuntu version. You can manually install `libc6` from other releases, but that can break other things.

Comment: Installing custom versions of kernels and important libraries (like `libc6`) should be for advanced users only. It may work, but it may also break things.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu isn't supposed to be used with mainline kernels. The Ubuntu Kernel PPA is not intended for general use, but for testing purposes and workarounds of some bugs and incompatibilities.

There should be a really good reason to install a mainline kernel to Ubuntu.

In your specific case. The `linux-headers-5.16.12-051612-generic` depends on

```
libc6 (>= 2.34)
libssl3
```

Ubuntu 20.04 that you are probably running has `libc6` version `2.31-0ubuntu9.9` and doesn't have `libssl3` package.

There is no simple way to override this. Installing unsupported packages can break other things in your system.

So if you don't have a really good reason for using a mainline kernel, stay with Ubuntu kernels that get latest security updates and bug fixes.